# Unable to connect to Node.js Express server from Browser

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node and express. I followed instructions from the book “Professional Node.js” by Pedro Teixeria. I have installed Node.js in my CentOS server hosted in Rackspace Cloud. Then I installed Express -

```
$ npm install -g express@2.5.x
```

This installed Express 2.5.11 and I can confirm it, with

```
$ which express
```

Then, I initialize my Application, with the following command

```
$ express my_app
```

This creates a folder my_app with default files. Lastly it also tells me to install the dependencies, which I do with the following command. Go inside my_app folder and issue the command

```
$ npm install
```

I edited the routes/index.js file. It is now like this -

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */
module.exports = function(app){
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
};
```

I created another file called users.js in routes. So my routes/users.js looks like this

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */
module.exports = function(app){
app.get('/users/:name', function(req, res){
  res.render('users/profile', { title: 'User Profile' });
});
};
```

Then I edited the app.’s file inside my_app (i.e., the main application folder). My app.’s now looks like this -

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

 app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

require('./routes/index')(app);
require('./routes/users')(app);

app.listen(5124, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

Now, I start the server with the following command, within my_app folder -

```
$ node app
```

I see the output  “Express server listening on port 5124 in development mode”

But, when I open my browser and type the URL 50.56.246.162:5124/users I see Fifrefox reporting “Unable to connect”
But, I should at least see some errors. The Instructions says, it should at least display “failed to locate view “users/index”, tried: etc. etc. etc.

Since I have done all the above from the Linux shell as root, so I also changed the permissions, so that it can be viewed from the browser. Also, I do not think I have to edit iptables to open ports.
What am I doing wrong.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you configured a web server (such as Apache or nginx) to serve your Node.js server endpoints?

Comment: I am not getting what you mean. Apache, Nginx should not be required, because Node.js Express itself creates a HTTP server.

Comment: As you're not serving your app on a standard port, you are going to need to either open that port in your iptables rules, or install a proxy (such as Apache or nginx) to allow you to reroute requests to the correct endpoint.  Given the above, I suggest you change your app to serve on a web-accessible port, then you won't need a proxy.

Comment: Thanks Stephen - you are right. I had to open the port.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea for you install the most up to date version using the Express application generator...

```
npm install express-generator -g

express my_app

cd my_app && npm install

SET DEBUG=my_app:* & npm start
```

Comment: I have done exactly like you specified. I want to know - what is so special about expres-generator? Also, after following your instructions, I checked the app.js inside my_app folder. Now, the app.js is totally different and there is no port number defined. In the earlier case, the port number is always 3000 by default. Since port number is now missing, how will I open it in the Browser?

Comment: It's quite possibly the fastest and most efficient way of building an application that works out of the box. The port number will be in bin/www - it will be 3000. Run the application using npm start, then go to your browser and enter 127.0.0.1:3000.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with Rackspace, rackspace doesn't allow you to access ports other than 80 and 8080. If you are using a shared environment, then port 80 will be already in use by apache. The way I fixed this issue is by installing nginx and run it on port 8080 and then create a reverse proxy for the node app. That is, any request coming to port 8080 of your shared host will be routed to whatever port on which you are running your node instance.

1. Install nginx
2. Edit /etc/nginx/conf.d]/default.conf file as given below

   server {
       listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
       server_name test.server;
       access_log /var/log/nginx/test.server.log;

   ```
   location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5124;
   }
   ```

   }

After that, start the node process and let it run in the background. A better option would be to use process managers like [pm2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps). Now if you go to 50.56.246.162:8081 in your browser, you should be taken to the app's page.

Comment: This is not correct. I have already created a http server in Node only (i.e., without Express) in Rackspace Cloud. This small chat app, uses the socket.io module and it is running successfully on some port. If you want, I can paste the code here. The server runs perfectly and multiple users can chat. Interestingly, I did not use iptables to open any ports.

However, I got stuck up somewhere using Express framework. I have no idea as to what is causing the issue.

Comment: As @Stephen Wright has mentioned in comments, you are not bale to access the app because it is running on a port that is not accessible by browser. I presume that your code works on local environment. Is that correct?